# Parallel arrows in commutative diagram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I would like to make all arrows that should be parallel in my commutative diagram, actually parallel. Here is my diagram:

```
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=3em]
    {
        F(\mu F) & FA \\
        \mu F & A \\};
    \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [left] {$ in_{F} $} (m-2-1)
    edge  node [above] {$F(h)$} (m-1-2)
    (m-2-1.east) edge node [above] {$h$}
    node [above] {} (m-2-2)
    (m-1-2) edge node [right] {$ g $} (m-2-2)
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

How can I shift this away and get a proper square?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than a matrix, use a specialized extension of TikZ, namely `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
F(\mu F) \arrow[r, "F(h)"] \arrow[d, "\mathit{in}_{F}"'] & FA \arrow[d, "g"] \\
\mu F \arrow[r, "h"] & A
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The syntax is more natural, the labels have their proper size and the arrows are like in the overall math font.

[image]

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much for your edit. You are a true Friend. Always thanks of all. Sebastiano

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge] % <---
    F(\mu F)
    \arrow{r}{F(h)} 
    \arrow{d}{in_F}
&
    FA
    \arrow{d}{g}   \\
%
    A
    \arrow{r}{h}
&
    (\mu F)
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

oh, the answer is almost the same as of [sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117876/sebastiano) :-(. well diagram is little bit more squarish :-)

Comment: @Zarko You do not have to worry at all if your answer is similar to mine. I always appreciate and vote for those who offer their time for others. I always bow to the best. A dear greeting.

Comment: @Tcraft We are here to help each other. At the end of this life, what is left?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually quite a small change to make that would fix things that may interest you, as it is useful in other parts of LaTeX as well. The problem here is that `\mu` has a descender, while `FA` doesn't. You can get a box that has "all the heights" associated with tall letters and descenders but no width via `\strut`, so:

```
    F(\mu F) & FA\strut \\
    \mu F & A\strut
```

The rest of the document can stay exactly the same. If you're feeling paranoid, you can add `\strut`s to the other cells as well as future-proofing in case you change their contents later.

More generally, you can use `\vphantom` for width-less boxes with the same height and depth parameters as a given other box and `\hphantom` for height-less boxes with the same width as a given other box. So the truly paranoid version would be

```
    F(\mu F)\vphantom{FA} & FA\vphantom{F(\mu F)} \\
    \mu F\vphantom{A} & A\vphantom{\mu F}
```

which would guarantee that you had the same height and depth across all columns in each row. (It would also have the advantage over `\strut` that it is "minimal" with respect to height and depth; e.g. if nothing in a given row had descenders, adding a `\strut` everywhere would give it depth but using `\vphantom` as above would not.)